# Is the countable union of disjoint compact sets compact?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the countable union of $\textbf{disjoint}$ compact sets compact?

I can't think of any counterexamples and it seems intuitively true...

Comment: Is $\Bbb N$ compact in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: But a countable union of disjoint compact sets **may** be compact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is not in general. Take for instance the sets $[2n, 2n+1]$ for $n=1,2,3,...$. These include $[0,1], [2,3], [4,5],..., \text{etc.}$. They are disjoint, and their union is unbounded. Thus the union is not compact.

If you want a counter example where the union is still bounded, consider $\left[ \frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2n+1} \right]$ for $n=1,2,3,...$. The intervals are compact and disjoint. The union is still bounded. However the union is not closed. You can see this by taking the sequence of lower endpoints of the intervals. Notice that sequence converges to $0$, but this is not in the union.