# Is the union of a countable number of disjoint compact sets never compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

As above, I have read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145535/is-the-countable-union-of-disjoint-compact-sets-compact) and it got me thinking. I have not yet been able to come up with a counterexample but I also don't know how to proceed in a way that convinces me there is no case in which the result is compact.

I don't need a proof, just something to kickstart my intution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Α counterexample is $A_n=\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $A_0=\{0\}$ on the real line with the usual topology.

The union is compact.

Comment: I think this depends on the definition of "union". How is the topology defined on the union?

Comment: @StinkingBishop with the usual topology on the real line..i edited.

Comment: So it is worth noting that this is not the same topology as the one given by the disjoint union of the topological spaces $A_n, n\ge 0$ (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology) ) - the latter is discrete topology and is not compact.

Comment: @StinkingBishop i did not talk about topological subspaces...just subsets of the real line,with the topology on the real line

Comment: In this example, does the union have any accumulation points? It would seem like it must by Bolzano-Weierstrass. The only one I can think of is 0. Does this set only have one accumulation point?

Comment: @ParkerWieck zero is the only accumulation point

Answer (score 2):

If $A_i, i\in I$ is an infinite family of nonempty topological spaces, then their disjoint union / direct sum (in the sense as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology) ) is never compact.

Namely, every $A_i$ can be viewed as an open subset of the disjoint union, and those $A_i$ therefore make an open cover of the union which doesn't have a finite subcover.

Comment: Why would A_i have an open subset? What if A_i is a singleton?

Comment: It is still open in itself, and the disjoint union (as a topological construction) *inherits that*, that is the point.